# How to read parameters from json file and put them in the setUpClass(cls)

Tags: python, python-unittest

Is there a way python unittest to read parameters from file and assign them to setUpClass(cls)?

**Example:**

I have json file, that contains:

```
{
    "browserType" : "Chrome",
    "ip" : "11.111.111.111",
    "port" : 4444
}
```

Decorator:

```
def params_from_file(file):
    """Decorator to load params from json file."""
    def decorator(func_to_decorate):
        @wraps(func_to_decorate)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with open(file, 'r') as fh:
                kwargs = json.loads(fh.read())
                return func_to_decorate(self, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Test class:

```
class H5Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    @params_from_file("file.json")
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.ip = ip
        cls.browser_type = browserType
        cls.port = port
        # some more code

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # some code

    def test_open_welcome_page(self):
        # some code for the test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you can use decorator, pass json file to it, load data from file and use as decorated function's params, change your unittest `.py` file to be like this:

```
import unittest
import json
from functools import wraps

def params_from_file(file):
    """Decorator to load params from json file."""
    def decorator(func_to_decorate):
        @wraps(func_to_decorate)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with open(file, 'r') as fh:
                kwargs = json.loads(fh.read())
                return func_to_decorate(self, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class H5Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    @params_from_file("file.json") #{"browserType": "Chrome", "ip": "11.111.111.111", "port":4444 }
    def setUpClass(cls, browserType, ip, port):#here you can put them in
        cls.browser_type = browserType
        cls.ip = ip
        cls.port = port
        # some more code

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        # some code

    def test_open_welcome_page(self):
        # some code for the test
        # here you can use them in test cases        
        print(self.ip) #11.111.111.111
        print(self.browser_type) #Chrome
        print(self.port) #4444
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, works perfect. May I ask you this: If my json file has more attributes than I need, how to ignore them. For example if there is also "os": "Windows", but my setUpClass(cls, ip, browserType, port) don't use this os, how can I easy get rid of it.

Comment: @stefan.stt what's your next question?

Comment: Actually I got how to do it, just need to add **kwargs to setUpClass(cls, ip, browserType, port, **kwargs). Thank you very much once more for your support, cheers!

Comment: @stefan.stt nice update, hope it will help others as well, cheers!

Comment: Why am I getting signature of the method setUpClass does not match with that of the base class TestCase?